# Write and Display a stream with format on C

Tags: c, scanf, printf

I'm in my first year of Computer Sciences and I have to design a procedure that writes to a file with format (`fprintf`) and displays it with format (`fscanf`). But I can't get it to run properly; it compiles but when it gets to the `fscanf` part, it crashes. I've been looking around reference sites, YouTube videos and stuff but I can't get it to work without any success.

Except for the last 2 lines of codes, it does everything great. Its capable of writing the records I enter, in the `.txt` file. The problem is with the use of `fscanf` itself.

```
void write_with_format()
{
    char  name_of_file[100] = "grades.txt";
    FILE *arch;
    arch = fopen (name_of_file, "a");
    char name[50];
    char career[50];
    char grades[100];
    char total;
    printf("Give me the name");
    gets(name);
    printf("Give me the career");
    gets(career);
    printf("Give me the grade");
    gets(grades);

    getchar();
    fprintf (arch, "%s,%s,%s\n",name,career,grades);

    fscanf(arch,"%s %s %f",&name,&career,&grades);

    printf("%s %s %f",name,career,grades);
}
```

I'd appreciate any help regarding my code or the proper use of `fscanf`, thank you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. This line is all wrong:

   `fscanf(arch,"%s %s %f",&name,&career,&grades);`

   `grades` is declared as `char grades[100];`, ie. a string, however you're trying to read a  `float` into it.  Same goes for the `printf` line below it, you're using `%f` and telling `printf` that you're passing a float, however you're passing an array. You also don't need to use the *address-of* operator (`&`) when passing arrays to functions, as you have with `fscanf`.
2. You should use `fclose` to flush the buffer and close the file stream once you're done with reading/writing a file.
3. Back to the `fscanf` line, what exactly do you expect it to do? The *file position inidcator* is at the end of the file, just after where you've *appended* the line produced by `fprintf`. Check the return value of `fscanf` and you'll see that it's returning `EOF` to report an error. The specific error value is stored in `errno`.
4. You can use `rewind` or `fseek` to set the position to the start of the file or back a certain amount, or you could always reopen the file. I know that I at least wouldn't have my read code in a `write_with_format` function.
5. `gets` is unsafe and should not be used as it has the potential to cause buffer overflows, use `fgets(stdin, SIZE...)` instead.
6. Turn up your compiler warnings. If by chance you're using gcc, the flag is `-Wall`. Just because your code compiles, doesn't mean that it's going to work properly (or at all).

Answer (score 0):

You declare grades as an array of char's but are trying to read into it a float.